# How do I start using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on creating a friends analyser application with the Facebook Graph API. I think I successfully created a canvas app on Facebook, but beyond this I have no idea what I should do to explore my Facebook profile and gather confidential data from friends to analyse their personalities. (For example, I would like to extract hobbies of my friends. I realized they are generally fond of of rock music. And according to the number of "likes"
they have, 60% of my friends are addicted to Facebook (20 likes per day).)

Of course, Facebook gave me an APPid and secureid. But after that I don't know what I must do.

Here are links that I visited to find solutions:

https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/readme.md
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/develop-facebook-app/

Comment: Please explain why the links you visited didn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your Facebook quest by reading documentation provided by Facebook.

This is the URL that shows various API endpoints exposed by Facebook: [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

In order to retrieve information from Facebook, you need to implement the OAuth authentication model so that your Facebook app is allowed to access the required information.